# Show only whitespaces in Atom (not EOL)

Tags: whitespace, atom-editor, eol

If I choose `Show Invisibles` in Atom settings, then all invisible characters become visible:

[image]

I would like to hide EOLs, because they pollute the view.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no ui-option for this, but it is achievable via Atom config:

```cson
"*":
  editor:
    invisibles:
      eol: false
```

Also you can hide tabs and spaces if you want:

```cson
"*":
  editor:
    invisibles:
      eol: false
      tab: false
      space: false
```

**UPDATE**

Atom has been changed since the original answer, and now it has UI to config invisibles:

[image: Invisibles menu block]

Comment: Found, you should also hide "cr" - cr: false

Comment: @imkost how do you get to that ui panel?

Comment: weird bug in 1.9.9, you have to have both eol and cr set to false, otherwise it just prints the word false at each line break

Comment: I can see these options, but they aren't working for me.

Comment: Using 1.16.0. There are options to change the character for each type of whitespace, but no individual checkboxes to (temporarily) disable each type, only a master checkbox for all invisibles. Annoying when sometimes you only want to be alerted about tabs usage and don't care about other whitespace. Manually editing config.cson did the trick though, so thanks @imkost.

Comment: There is no ui-option for this in Windows 10 64-bit version but as mentioned in the answer it is achievable via Atom config but a little tweak is needed. The boolean value doesn't work. Had to add `eol: ''` instead of `eol: false`. With the latter value `false` started appearing as EOL char. `cr: ''` also worked for me by hiding the CR characters. Thanks for this blog post http://www.dangtrinh.com/2015/02/show-invisible-characters-in-atom.html for the tweak.